# .Net Maui Class library Dependancy injection for Platform specific code plugin

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am trying to create a plugin using .Net Maui class libraries that use native Android and iOS code. I tried using the Dependency Service using the Interface, but I get a null point when I try to Register the Interface.
Shared code

```
public class MyPlugin
{
   public static DisplayModel()
   {
      IDeviceOrientationService service = 
      DependencyService.Get<IMyPlugin>();
      var model = service.GetDeviceName();
   }
}

public Interface IMyPlugin
{
  string GetDeviceName();
}
```

Android platform

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyPlugin))]
public class MyPlugin:IMyPlugin
{
   public string GetDeviceName
   {
      return "From Android";
   }
}
```

This is just an example. Please help me understand if I am not going about this the correct way and any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want to develop a plugin that third parties can use or do you simply want to use platform-specific APIs? Then, .NET MAUI or Xamarin.Forms? You've added both tags, but if you develop a plugin for MAUI, you won't be targeting Xamarin.Forms (the other way round is possible, but quite complex). What is your solution's setup? Apart from that, why is the `DisplayModel()` method `static`? You also shouldn't use the same name for the implementation and the calling class, you have `MyPlugin` declared twice that way. In MAUI, you don't need the DependencyService.

Comment: why is `Get<IMyPlugin>` returning `IDeviceOrientationService`?

Comment: You can try to use the `#if` to run the platform specific code in the .net maui.